# Go blocking from receiving channel

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

I have the following go code to wait for streams. The expected output is:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
escape1
scan done
done....
```

But after `line5`, my code keeps hanging.

```
var lines = `
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
`

func main() {
    var (
        donec  = make(chan struct{})
        stream = make(chan string, 5000)
        exitc  = make(chan struct{})
    )
    go func() {
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(lines))
    escape1:
        for {
            for scanner.Scan() {
                select {
                case <-donec:
                    fmt.Println("escape1")
                    close(stream)
                    break escape1
                default:
                    stream <- scanner.Text()
                }
            }
        }
        close(exitc)
        fmt.Println("scan done")
        return
    }()

escape2:
    for {
        select {
        case txt, ok := <-stream:
            if !ok {
                fmt.Println("stream closed!")
            }
            fmt.Println(txt)
            if strings.Contains(txt, "line5") {
                close(donec)
                <-exitc
                break escape2
            }
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("done....")
}
```

Think I am doing everything right. Could anybody help me debug this hanging code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because your `escape1` for loop wraps the `for scanner.Scan()` loop.

When I remove that outer for loop it works fine for me: https://play.golang.org/p/NU3m3Deil7

```
func main() {
    var (
        donec  = make(chan struct{})
        stream = make(chan string, 5000)
        exitc  = make(chan struct{})
    )
    go func() {
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(lines))
    escape1:
        for scanner.Scan() {
            select {
            case <-donec:
                fmt.Println("escape1")
                close(stream)
                break escape1
            default:
                stream <- scanner.Text()
            }
        }

        close(exitc)
        fmt.Println("scan done")
        return
    }()

escape2:
    for {
        select {
        case txt, ok := <-stream:
            if !ok {
                fmt.Println("stream closed!")
            }
            fmt.Println(txt)
            if strings.Contains(txt, "line5") {
                close(donec)
                <-exitc
                break escape2
            }
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("done....")
}
```